# Как запустить NodeJS скрипт из PHP через PM2

Tags: php, node.js, pm2

PHP код:

```
echo(shell_exec('pm2 start chat_server'));
```

Что выдаёт:

```
                        -------------

__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\____/\\\\____________/\\\\____/\\\\\\\\\_____
 _\/\\\/////////\\\_\/\\\\\\________/\\\\\\__/\\\///////\\\___
  _\/\\\_______\/\\\_\/\\\//\\\____/\\\//\\\_\///______\//\\\__
   _\/\\\\\\\\\\\\\/__\/\\\\///\\\/\\\/_\/\\\___________/\\\/___
    _\/\\\/////////____\/\\\__\///\\\/___\/\\\________/\\\//_____
     _\/\\\_____________\/\\\____\///_____\/\\\_____/\\\//________
      _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\___/\\\/___________
       _\/\\\_____________\/\\\_____________\/\\\__/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_
        _\///______________\///______________\///__\///////////////__


                          Community Edition

            Production Process Manager for Node.js applications
                     with a built-in Load Balancer.


                Start and Daemonize any application:
                $ pm2 start app.js

                Load Balance 4 instances of api.js:
                $ pm2 start api.js -i 4

                Monitor in production:
                $ pm2 monitor

                Make pm2 auto-boot at server restart:
                $ pm2 startup

                To go further checkout:
                http://pm2.io/


                        -------------
```

Скрипт не запускается. Возможно, что PM2 не может работать с файлами.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить расширение `chat_server.js`.

Comment: @KostaB. Даже с ним не работает

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой пример назвал файл `server.js`

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.write('Hello World!'); //write a response to the client
  res.end(); //end the response
}).listen(8080); //the server object listens on port 8080
```

Другой файл `init.php`

```
<?php

echo(shell_exec('pm2 start server.js'));
```

оба файла в одной директории и команда:

```
$ php -f init.php
```

Все работает.